# How do I find the real and imaginary part of $z+ e^z $

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponential-sum

How can I find the imaginary and real part of $z + e^z$ ?

I tried but I only get $$x + yi + e^x e^{yi}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:**

You are on the right track.  Note that $e^{iy}=\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$.